# Disable UASP on Windows 10 build 1607

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-3, uasp

Is there anyway to disable USB 3 UASP (USB Attached SCSI Protocol) support on Windows 10 build 1607 for devices which use Microsoft's drivers, and force the attached devices to communicate in BOT mode instead?

Comment: why do you want to do this? Sounds like a XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Troubleshooting compatibility issues with a iSCSI VTL.

Comment: set the start value to 4 (disabled) (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959920.aspx) in registry under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UASPStor

Comment: have you tried this? Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The UASP is implemented in the driver `uaspstor.sys`. [To disable loading of this driver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959920.aspx), run regedit, and set the `start` value to `4` (disabled) under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UASPSto‌​r`

Now reboot and look what happens.

Comment: That does disable UASP support, however it does not force the attached device to use BOT mode instead.

Comment: how do yo use this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand? As you recommended I changed the start value to 4, however it simply caused the device to stuck in an error state when viewed in the device manager. As I mentioned this disabled UASP mode which was the first half of my question, but it failed to force the device to use BOT mode instead which was the second half.

Comment: Run `sc config UASPStor start= disabled` in cmd does the same but neither of them is a solution. It prevents the driver from loading but doesn't workaround the issue making the device functional..