# how do I disable usap as my docking station corrupts the drive currently

Tags: usb-3, uasp

My hard drive works fine using USB3/UASP on my laptop. However if I plug it into the Dell d3100 docking station then it reports file corruption and I have to reformat the disk.

I am guessing D3100 does not support UASP but was a bit surprised it destroyed all the data. is there any way to disable UASP so I can plug the drive into my docking station even if it is slower.

Comment: D3100 seems to support UASP. https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Triple-Monitor-Docking-Station/dp/B012VKW900 I can think of just dock working incorrectly with it.
To disable UASP follow https://superuser.com/questions/1149210/disable-uasp-on-windows-10-build-1607

Comment: The startech supports UASP. No mention of it re Dell D3100.
I was hoping to keep UASP for my laptop but just disable on the D3100 but looks like that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the wrong line. D3100 most probably doesn't support it